# Modified Newton method and contraction principle

Tags: analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I am studying Newton's method modified by the book Zorich, Mathematical analysis II, page 39,40:

[image]

[image]

It seems to me, if I make no mistakes, that there is a problem in the derivative of $ A (x) $. The author says that $ | A '(x) | = | [f' (x_0)] ^ {- 1} \cdot f '(x) | $, while I would say that:

$$ | A '(x) | = | 1- [f' (x_0)] ^ {- 1} \cdot f '(x) | $$

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your observation is correct. This is also confirmed by the fact that this corrected expression is the smaller the closer $f'(x_0)$ is to $f'(x)$, that is, the closer the step is to the Newton method.

Perhaps they mixed this up with the derivative of the Newton step where this first  term indeed cancels,
$$
N(x)=x-[f'(x)]^{-1}f(x)\implies N'(x)=I-I+[f'(x)]^{-1}[f''(x)][f'(x)]^{-1}f(x)
$$

Comment: Thank you, therefore the condition for $A(x)$ to be a contraction becomes this:
$$ 0 <[f '(x_0) ^ {- 1}] \cdot f' (x) <2 $$ 
right?

Comment: Yes. The closer to $1$ the better.